# How to change PyCharms docstring autocomplete?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have been programming in PyCharm for a little while now and I like it just fine however there is one little thing that is nagging at me, when I go to generate a new docstring for a function that I have defined PyCharm will autocomplete the docstring using what I believe is sphinx style formatting. Example in picture below:

[image: PyCharm default docstring autocomplete]

I'd like to change this format to something appear like the docstrings throughout the numpy module. Here is the beginning of the docstring for numpy.max for an example;

[image: Docstring for numpy.max]

Is there a way I can either A) quickly swap the PyCharm docstring autocomplete method or B) cumstomize the existing autocomplete method?

Comment: // , In the future, if you have questions about settings, you can search for them in the Settings search bar. In this case, you should have just searched `docstring`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can adjust this by going to the [Python Integrated Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/python-integrated-tools.html) settings.

#### On Windows/Linux

```
File -> Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools
```

#### On OS X

```
PyCharm -> Preferences -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools
```

Then there is a `Docstrings` section. Change the drop down format to `NumPy` and press "OK"

[image: Docstring format]